# GalleryView filmstrip pictures in panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery, galleryview

I am trying to add filmstrip to the picture gallery using [GalleryView](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview#) plug-in, version 2.0. I have a problem that the specified pictures in filmstrip (thumbnail pictures) are displayed in a panel **instead of the specified picture** in div (class="panel").

As is evident from examples and documentation, custom filmstrip can be added in the following way:

```
<ul class="filmstrip">
<li><img src="img/gallery/frame-01.jpg" alt="Effet du soleil" title="Effet du soleil" /></li>
<li><img src="img/gallery/frame-02.jpg" alt="Eden" title="Eden" /></li>
</ul>
```

My gallery looks like this:

```
<div id="gallery_wrap">
    <div id="photos" class="galleryview">
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="/upload/pic/IMG_02740_orig.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <img src="/upload/pic/IMG_02740_orig.jpg" />
        </div>
        <ul class="filmstrip">
            <li>
                <img src="/upload/pic/IMG_02739_thumb.jpg" alt="Effet du soleil" title="Effet du soleil" /></li>
            <li>
                <img src="/upload/pic/IMG_02739_thumb.jpg" alt="Eden" title="Eden" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing wrong? I have basically total copy-paste from example and it is not working. Does anyone successfully implement this filmstrip section in GalleryView?

How it looks:

[alt text http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/852/galleryviewfilmstripima.jpg](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/852/galleryviewfilmstripima.jpg)

You can clearly see that in panel is a thumbnail pic instead of the original (totally different picture than thumbnail).

I am using the following setting object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#photos').galleryView({
                panel_width: 800,
                panel_height: 300,
                frame_width: 100,
                frame_height: 38,
                transition_speed: 1200,
                background_color: '#222',
                border: 'none',
                easing: 'easeInOutBack',
                pause_on_hover: true,
                nav_theme: 'custom',
                overlay_height: 52,
                filmstrip_position: 'top',
                overlay_position: 'top'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Not quiet sure what's going wrong, can your post a screenshot detail the problem further?

Comment: Is now more clear what is going on?

Comment: what galleryview version are you using, is it 2.0?

Comment: and what javascript are you using for configuration?

Comment: Yes, I am using version 2.0. I have also added JavaScript conf. object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case issue is related to [GalleryView 2.0](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/galleryview-2.0.zip), see samples for it, there are changes in images list preparation: you don't need to use thumbnails anymore...
Your'e gallery description should look like

```
<div id="gallery_wrap">
   <ul id="gallery">
      <li>
         <span class="panel-overlay">Effet du soleil</span>
         <img src="/upload/pic/IMG_02740_orig.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
         <span class="panel-overlay">Eden</span>
         <img src="/upload/pic/IMG_02740_orig.jpg" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

anyway, see [GalleryView 2.0 sample](http://appleton.me/galleryview/)

Comment: Yeas I know this, but I would like to use a custom thumbnails. How to to this? I have do exactly as in examples but it does not work.

Comment: you should use http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery-galleryview-1.1.zip for custom icons

Comment: What? Version 1.1? 2.0 does not support custom filmstrip??

Comment: correct, no separate definition for filmstrip & icons in version 2.0. icons are generated from images.

Comment: thanks that helped me out, any idea why the left and right arrows might not be showing up on mine ?

Comment: have no idea, but this may be a css issue.

Comment: I figured it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688011/loading-galleryview-script-using-jquery-causes-problem

Answer (score 0):

it IS possible to have custom thumbnails:

```
<ul id="gallery">
   <li><img class="panel-content" src="path/to/image" /><img src="path/to/thumbnail" /></li>
</ul>
```

but panel-overlay won't work anymore. 5 Seconds of code reading brought me there :)