# loading GalleryView script using jquery causes problem

Tags: jquery, galleryview

I am using GalleryView  and when load the script in the head like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/galleryview/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/galleryview/jquery.galleryview-2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/galleryview/jquery.timers-1.2.js"></script>
```

everything works fine but when I use jquery to load the like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gallery').hide();

    $('<link />').appendTo('head').attr({
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: '/js/galleryview/galleryview.css'
    });
    $.getScript('/js/galleryview/jquery.easing.1.3.js', function() {
        $.getScript('/js/galleryview/jquery.galleryview-2.1.js', function() {
            $.getScript('/js/galleryview/jquery.timers-1.2.js', function() {
                $('#gallery').show();
                $('#gallery').galleryView({
                    transition_speed: 1200,
                    background_color: '#006',
                    border: 'none',
                    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
                    pause_on_hover: true
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I get 404 on the nav buttons

http://mydoamian/undefineddark/prev.gif

http://mydoamian/undefineddark/next.gif

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have to load the js like that? It seems very complex given that it could be way more simple - it probably doesn't help either that you load them with nested callbacks.

Comment: I want to load them that way because I don't want to load them on every page in my cms just on specific pages. where I am using the galleryView and I have the nested callbacks so I know when its ok to run the galleryView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get around this by modifying the code at line 853 by defining theme path as an empty string first

```
        $('script').each(function(i){
            var s = $(this);
            theme_path = '';
            if(s.attr('src') && s.attr('src').match(/jquery\.galleryview/)){
                loader_path = s.attr('src').split('jquery.galleryview')[0];
                theme_path = s.attr('src').split('jquery.galleryview')[0]+'themes/';
            }
```

then in my  call to galleryView I define nav_theme appropriately

```
$('#gallery').hide();
$('<link />').appendTo('head').attr({
rel: 'stylesheet',
type: 'text/css',
href: prefix +'js/galleryview/galleryview.css'
});
$.getScript(prefix +'js/galleryview/jquery.easing.1.3.js', function() {
      $.getScript(prefix +'js/galleryview/jquery.galleryview-2.1.js', function() {
        $.getScript(prefix +'js/galleryview/jquery.timers-1.2.js', function() {
                            $('#gallery').show();
            $('#gallery').galleryView({
                transition_speed: 1200,
                background_color: '#006',
                border: 'none',
                easing: 'easeInOutBack',
                nav_theme:prefix +"js/galleryview/themes/dark"
            });
        });
    });
});
```